# Setting Button Color in Extended Button Class

Tags: android, button, colors, extension-methods

This is really confusing me. I've extended the `Button` class as follows:

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    // Default colours/styles
    private int myButtonDrawable = R.drawable.button_drawable;
    private int myButtonTextColor = R.color.white_text;

    // Constructors
    public MyButton (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    // Override setEnabled to apply custom colors/styles
    @Override
    public void setEnabled (boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);

        if (enabled) {
            this.setBackgroundResource(myButtonDrawable);
            this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(myButtonTextColor));
        }

    }
```

Thus by using setters I can set values for `myButtonDrawable` and `myButtonTextColor` for each `MyButton` object, and they will be applied when I enable the button using the method `setEnabled` (i.e. when true).

However, the above code does not work. It crashes out with logcat

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class
```

The error is occuring with the line

```
this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(myButtonTextColor));
```

which is really weird because it works fine if I use

```
this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_text));
```

where the resource `white_text` is defined as

```
<color name="white_text">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

I don't understand why replacing `R.color.white_text` with the class member `myButtonTextColor` causes the activity to crash. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a <resources> tag around your <color> tag?

Comment: Yep. Have a resources tag around all my colours. Pretty sure if I didn't then `this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_text))` wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:  You are extending `Button`.  `Button` extends `TextView`, which reads from its XML attributes and calls `setEnabled(boolean)` *in its constructor*.  However, you have overridden `setEnabled()` and that method now refers to fields defined in your subclass by initializers.

The initializers for your subclass are not run before the constructor of the superclass.  Therefore, at the time `setEnabled()` is first called by the superclass constructor, `myButtonTextColor` has the default value and resolving it with `Resources.getColor()` will throw an error.

If you persist in doing this in code, you may move your if statement to the constructor of your subclass:

```
public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (isEnabled()) {
        setBackgroundResource(myButtonDrawable);
        //FYI, there is a setTextColor method that accepts a color ID.
        setTextColor(myButtonTextColor);
    }
}
```

since at the time the constructor of your *subclass* is called, your initializers are guaranteed to have run, and the superclass constructor will have already resolved the attributes from XML.

[Here](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html) is an excellent explanation if you'd like to dive more deeply into exactly how Java works in this regard.

---

There is a better approach for what you want to do.  Use a standard Android `Button` and in your XML (or in code), set a selector as the background and color of your button.  You can define an appearance for your button's enabled state -- and many others, including pressed, focused, etc.  Android will handle changing the appearance for you.

In your activity (or you can do this in XML):

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setTextColor(R.drawable.button_text_color);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
```

drawable/button_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/white_text" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey_text" />
</selector>
```

drawable/button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_enabled="true" android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"/> 
     <item android:background="@drawable/button_disabled_drawable"/> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks Lisa. Yes, I considered doing this, and may well end up going this route. However, I was trying to do it more programatically to reduce the proliferation of xml files, i.e., if you have quite a few different colours/backgrounds that you want to apply, you're very quickly going to end up with a lot of xml, when I should just be able to apply a method to the object. I still think its weird why my original code doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: In my opinion, XML files are there to reduce the proliferation of code :)  I will add to my answer above to explain why your code is crashing.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks Lisa. Just about got my head round all that.